# How to validate date input to set it always 2 days of current day using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a date input

```
<input type="date" id="a" name="a" required />
```

Now i want its value to be set by user but it has to be set only after two days of current day, how do i do that using javascript or jquery?

What i already tried is -

```
<form id="f">
    <input type="date" id="d" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>    

$("#f").submit( function(e){
    var date=new Date();
    date = date.getDate()+2;
    if($("#d").val()<date){
        alert("fail");
        e.preventDefault();
    }else{
        alert("Success");
    }
} );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a date object and compare it to another date object set 2 days ahead.

**See Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/g6aFz/

### JS:

```
$("#f").submit( function(e){
    var $date = $("#a"),
        date = new Date($date.val()),
        date2 = new Date()
    
    date2.setDate(date2.getDate() + 2)
    
    if(date < date2){
        alert("fail");
        e.preventDefault();
    }else{
        alert("Success");
    }
} );
```

Answer (score 2):

The date = date.getDate()+2; might now work as you intended. To increment dates in javascript, do as outlined in this post: [Add days to JavaScript Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563406/add-days-to-datetime)

```
var today = new Date();
var dayAfterTomorrow = new Date();
dayAfterTomorrow.setDate(today.getDate()+2);
```